# Emulator freezes randomly

Tags: android, performance, emulation, freeze

My emulator freezes and I keep getting this message "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. Skipped x frames"
And yes, X is a number much higher than 100 mostly. I checked all over Internet and I checked my app, it's not doing too much work on the main thread. I made tests, I looked for huge images/background images, no I don't use any. 
What is more interesting, I even created a new project with only one/blank Activity, I launched it and I have the same problem. Emulator is slow and I get "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

My emulator finally starts working normal randomly and I don't have this problem until the first windows restart/shut down-start. So if I keep my computer in stand by and then use the Emulator it works for days.. but if I shut down my computer and start it again, I most likely have this problem again: my emulator working terribly slow. 
Any ideas would be appreciated. I just keep having this problem and I can't use the emulator at all.

Comment: A little off-topic: Do you have to use the Android Studio emulator? Try genymotion (desktop). I think it's performance is much better/faster and it 
is easier to use :)

Comment: I didn't know about genymotion but I will check it out! thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the Configuration of Android Virtual Device:
Emulated Performance > Graphics > Change from Hardware to Software.
If your emulator is still slow, create another emulator with low configuration and low Graphics(Resolution).
You can also use your Android Device or Bluestack For testing apps.

Comment: Thank you!! I made the next changes: Change the resolution of the emulator to Nexus One 480×800 pixels and change in Emulated Performance > Graphics from Hardware to Software and now I am able to use the emulator! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on macOS you may not be able to change the hardware acceleration. You'll see the button is grayed out. To enable it you must create a new emulator using a Google APIs image instead of Google Play image.

[image: Select Google APIs, not Google Play]