# Android studio emulator.exe freezing like dubstap :) how to fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Emulator is freezing always, I need to tap somewhere. https://vimeo.com/283369007  My PC is not loaded so much, emulator eating 13-30% of CPU, GPU is always loaded to 5-10%.

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44679489/5110595)

Comment: try to update your GPU driver or use a different emulator like genymotion

Comment: I need emulator for HTTP API debugging :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do update:

```
C:\Users\Marat\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools>android.bat update sdk
```